# Not able to write a stock close to a certain excel cell

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, yfinance

I would like to write a Stock close read with yfinance in an excel file with openpyxl

```py
import yfinance as yf
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd

data=yf.download('UCG.MI','2019-10-29','2019-10-30')

wb = load_workbook('path/Esempio.xlsx') 
ws  = wb['Sheet1']

x=data.iloc[[0],[3]]

ws['B3']=x
wb.save('path/Esempio.xlsx')
```

I have an error

> 'cannot convert Close'

Comment: Why don't you use `pandas.read_excel` and `pandas.write_excel`?

Comment: don't know because I am new with Python, do you think it would be better?

Comment: ***"do you think it would be better"***: If you alread have to use `pandas`, here `x=data.iloc...`, there is no need to bother with `openpyxl`. About your error: The result of `x=data.iloc` is of type `pandas.Series` this type is not compatible with `openpyxl.Cell.value`.

Answer (score 0):

When using iloc with list, it will return a pd.Series, do this instead.

```py
x=data.iloc[0,3]
```

You can also save your entire dataframe doing this.

```py
data.to_excel('path/Esempio.xlsx')
```

Comment: Now I don't have the error but it writes all the data frame , I want to write only the close. I dont't know  I have x=data.iloc[0,3] and if I print (x) I have only the close while with ws['B3']=x it writes all the dataframe

Comment: OK with data.to_excel('path/Esempio.xlsx') it writes all the dataframe while with wb.save(path/esempio.xlsx) it writes only the cell